# Several arguments in SumIF in VBA?

Tags: vba, if-statement, sum

In cont. of a previous questions, I am looking to include several statements in a sumif command. Can that be done by using something similar to this code:

```
For i = 1 To 10

Range("G" & i + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
        Arg1:=Ark1.Range("A2:A11") And Ark1.Range("B2:B11"), _
        Arg2:=Range("A" & i + 1) And "a", _
        Arg3:=Ark1.Range("C2:C11"))

 Next i
```

I get the following error message: "Run-time error 13. Type Mismatch"

Comment: A proper statement is: `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`. See: [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: Seems, you want to use formula array. See: [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for that. However, I cannot use Arg1 ... to ... Arg5. This gives an error message too.